# Con trigger deseo insertar datos en producto y se registre en el inventario, solo me salen dos (0)

Tags: mysql, trigger

```
create table inventario 
/* Alias = i */
(
codprod_inven int not null,
marcaprod_inven varchar (30) not null,
nomprod_inven varchar (30) not null,
descripprod_inven varchar (80) not null,
catprod_inven varchar (30) not null,
exisprod_inven int not null
);

create table producto
/*Alias = pr */
(
cod_prod int not null primary key,
nom_prod varchar (30) not null,
id_unimed_prod int not null,
marca_prod varchar (30) not null,
descrip_prod varchar (80),
precunit_prod double not null,
exis_prod int not null,
fecha_venc_prod date not null,
lote_prod varchar (15) not null,
estado_prod enum ('disponible','agotado'),
img_prod blob,
idcat_prod int not null,
foreign key (idcat_prod) references categoria (id_categoria),
foreign key (id_unimed_prod) references uni_medida (id_unimed)  
);

create trigger invenañade_producto after insert on producto
for each row
 insert into inventario  (codprod_inven,
marcaprod_inven ,
nomprod_inven ,
descripprod_inven ,
catprod_inven ,
exisprod_inven)
 values(codprod_inven ,
marcaprod_inven ,
nomprod_inven ,
descripprod_inven ,
catprod_inven ,
exisprod_inven);


insert into producto
values(101120,'Queso',3,'Del campo','Queso tajado','500',10,'2021-02-12','2020M','disponible','',1)
```

Nota: el tres hace referencia al id de unidad de medida y el 1 final a id de la categoría.

EL producto se añade en su tabla pero en inventario solo se añade el codigo en (0) y las existencias en (0), los demas campos quedan en blanco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo una opción un poco más compacta, para que te líes menos con los nombres de los campos:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventario_after_insert 
  AFTER INSERT
  ON producto FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO inventario
  SELECT cod_prod,marca_prod,nom_prod,
    descrip_prod,idcat_prod,exis_prod
    FROM producto
    WHERE cod_prod=NEW.cod_prod;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: #David JP Gracias, me había surgido esa duda si se podía realizar de ese modo, pero no tenía idea de como era el procedimeinto.

Comment: ¿Has conseguido hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: si señor muchas gracias...!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te hace falta decir que esos campos vienen del NEW que en MYSQL es donde se obtiene lo que se afecto, creo que te quedaria de este modo.

```
create trigger invenañade_producto after insert on producto
for each row
 insert into inventario  (codprod_inven,
marcaprod_inven ,
nomprod_inven ,
descripprod_inven ,
catprod_inven ,
exisprod_inven)
 values(NEW.codprod_inven ,
NEW.marcaprod_inven ,
NEW.nomprod_inven ,
NEW.descripprod_inven ,
NEW.catprod_inven ,
NEW.exisprod_inven);


insert into producto
values(101120,'Queso',3,'Del campo','Queso tajado','500',10,'2021-02-12','2020M','disponible','',1)
```

En **NEW** va el nombre que viene yo suponiendo que asi se llaman igual les puse el nombre pero si no solo es poner el nombre correcto.

Comment: Edgar Vazquez, pero cuando le pongo el NEW. me sale este error Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'codprod_inven' in 'NEW'

Comment: Por eso te comentaba, que NEW tiene los campos que se insertaron en producto entonces pondrias el nombre del campo correspondiente que va entiendo que lo que se inserto en producto de ahi te basas para meterlo a inventario no? ejemplo este que insertas marcaprod_inven creo que es el que en la tabla producto esta como marca_prod entonces seria NEW.marca_prod